# How to get the highest value in a row together with the column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 10 columns, eight of them are columns with dates. My desired outcome is to get max date for each row (what I have already accomplished) but I would also like to get the name of the columns, which this max dates come from.

```
    SELECT s.sp_id
,s.sp_numer
,(
    SELECT MAX(Data_przedawnienia_update)
    FROM (
        VALUES (Data_przedawnienia_Postanowienie_o_umorzeniu_egzekucji)
            ,(Data_przedawnienia_Egzekucja_w_toku)
            ,(Data_przedawnienia_Nakaz_zaplaty_z_klauzula)
            ,(Data_przedawnienia_Nakaz_zaplaty)
            ,(Data_przedawnienia_Sprawa_sadowa_w_toku)
            ,(Data_przedawnienia_Wplaty_na_etapie_polubownym)
            ,(Data_przedawnienia_Umowa_ugody)
            ,(Data_przedawnienia_Wypowiedzenie_umowy)
        ) AS Data_przedawnienia(Data_przedawnienia_update)
    ) AS Data_przedawnienia_update
FROM dm_data_bps.dbo.sprawa AS s
INNER JOIN dm_data_bps.dbo.cache_sprawa_info AS csi ON s.sp_id = csi.sp_id
AND sprawa_zamknieta = 0
LEFT JOIN ##Postanowienie_o_umorzeniu_egzekucji AS umorzenie ON s.sp_id =       
umorzenie.sp_id
LEFT JOIN ##Egzekucja_w_toku AS egzekucja ON s.sp_id = egzekucja.sp_id
LEFT JOIN ##Nakaz_zaplaty_z_klauzula AS nakaz_kl ON s.sp_id = nakaz_kl.sp_id
LEFT JOIN ##Nakaz_zaplaty AS nakaz ON s.sp_id = nakaz.sp_id
LEFT JOIN ##Sprawa_sadowa_w_toku AS sprawa_sad ON s.sp_id = sprawa_sad.sp_id
LEFT JOIN ##Wplaty_na_etapie_polubownym AS wplaty_polubowny ON s.sp_id =   
wplaty_polubowny.sp_id
LEFT JOIN ##Umowa_ugody AS ugoda ON s.sp_id = ugoda.sp_id
LEFT JOIN ##Wypowiedzenie_umowy AS wypowiedzenie ON s.sp_id = 
wypowiedzenie.sp_id
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? (assuming this is not Sybase)

Comment: I use SQL Server 2012

Comment: One hint: Do not use global temp tables if there is the smallest chance, that two processes might use them at the same time...

Comment: What I'm going to to is to write a procedure in which I insert the data from above query into a global temp table and then I make an update on one table in  a production database using MERGE statement. I thought of table variable but I read that they don't use statistics and if one joins to other tables it's less time-consuming using temp table. What's your opinion?

Comment: @Arkadiusz read about global temp tables (`##`) and their behavior in concurrent access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML has great abilities to deal with generic queries:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,d1 DATE, d2 DATE, d3 DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('20180101','20180102','20180103')  --one max value
,('20170101','20190102','20190102'); --two max values

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       t.ID 
      ,y.value('text()[1]','date') d
      ,y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') c
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT d1,d2,d3 FOR XML PATH('d'),TYPE) A(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/d/*') B(y) 
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY y.value('text()[1]','date') DESC);
```

### UPDATE: Some explanation

The first `CROSS APPLY` will create an XML which looks like this:

```
<d>
  <d1>2018-01-01</d1>
  <d2>2018-01-02</d2>
  <d3>2018-01-03</d3>
</d>
```

The second `CROSS APPLY` uses `.nodes()` to return all nodes within `<d>`. With `.value()` we can get the element's name (`local-name()`) and its content.

The trick with `DENSE_RANK` and `TOP 1 WITH TIES` will return all rows which get a `1` (which are the highest per ID).

Comment: Nice! I was starting to think about adding another column to the values clause of the original query, but this seems like a much simpler solution

Comment: Great!,frankly speaking it would be straining a truth a little to say that I understand how it works but it does what I want.

Comment: @Arkadiusz I added some explanation

Comment: @Shnugo many thanks. I do like your trick with DENSE_RANK, I changed it for ROW_NUMBER to get only 1 row per ID if values are equal. Could you add some explanation to this syntax: 'text()[1]','date'  and 'local-name(.)','varchar(100)'             .

Comment: @Arkadiusz, Yes, `ROW_NUMBER` will return just one. Are you aware, that this result will be random? About the syntax just look for [XML in SQL-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and the native [XML methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Shnugo you mean that if there are 2 dates for one ID which are equal, ROW_NUMBER will return randomly one row? If so, it doesn't pose a problem for me because I need to know max date for each ID.

Comment: @shnugo it does matter and I thought about this issue. What crossed my mind was to use ConcatStrings but I would have to use GROUP BY and XML methods are not allowed in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Arkadiusz okay... To avoid chameleon questions please start a new question an place a link here. I think this can be solved with XQuery