# How to get the highest value in a row together with all columns' name for equal values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the highest value in a row together with the column's name. The problem is that there might be several values which are equal in one partition. So my desired outcome is to get the highest value in one column and all columns' name separeted by comma in such cases.

This question is correlated strictly with my previous one:

[How to get the highest value in a row together with the column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633476/how-to-get-the-highest-value-in-a-row-together-with-the-column-name#)

Let's use Shnugo's example from my previous question.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,d1 DATE, d2 DATE, d3 DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('20180101','20180102','20180103')  --one max value
,('20170101','20190102','20190102'); --two max values
```

For ID=2 there are two max values so what I'd like to accomplish is a table with ID column, max_date column and in the third column column's name. So for ID=2 I'd like to get two columns' name (d2,d3).

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: did you try MAX(column_name)? how did the result differ from your desired one?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,d1 DATE, d2 DATE, d3 DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('20180101','20180102','20180103')  --one max value
,('20170101','20190102','20190102'); --two max values

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
           t.ID 
          ,y.value('text()[1]','date') d
          ,y.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') c
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT d1,d2,d3 FOR XML PATH('d'),TYPE) A(x)
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/d/*') B(y) 
    ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY y.value('text()[1]','date') DESC)
)
SELECT cte1.ID
      ,cte1.d 
      ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + cte2.c 
        FROM cte cte2 
        WHERE cte1.ID=cte2.ID
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') cs
FROM cte cte1
GROUP BY ID,d;
```

With SQL-Server 2017+ you should better use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

I've added some explanation [at the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51633965/5089204)

Comment: thanks, it works but the problem is that the execution time is over 20 minutes  (still running) despite the fact that I created clustered indexes on all temp tables. Ideally, I'd like to have all columns' name if there are several max date for one ID but it seems to me that it might be too time-consuming.

Comment: @Arkadiusz If there are so many rows, this seems to be the wrong design... Your date columns should live in a related "status" table... Another option was a trigger on insert and update or a persitant computed column which sets an additional column to the values you need. You can maintain a side table, where you add a row, whenever one of these dates change. You should not compute this information *on the fly* for millions of rows. Btw: DBAs hate CPU consuming approaches on the db server...

Answer (score 0):

You can try similar code to get information and INSERT into table.You have to update the `CASE` logic below to add additional conditions, based on your need.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,d1 DATE, d2 DATE, d3 DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('20180301','20180102','20180103')  --one max value
,('20170101','20190102','20190102'); --two max values

SELECT ID, LEFT(MAXDateInfo,10) AS maxdate, RIGHT(maxdateInfo,2) as ColumnName
FROM
(SELECT ID,CASE WHEN d1 > d2 AND d1 > d3 THEN CONCAT(d1,'-','d1')
               WHEN d2 > d1 AND d2 > d3 THEN CONCAT(d2,'-','d2')
               WHEN d3 > d1 AND d3 > d3 THEN CONCAT(d3,'-','d3')
           END AS MAXDateInfo
FROM @tbl) as t
```